# Playing Video on iphone 3G with MPMoviePlayer

Tags: iphone, performance, mpmovieplayercontroller, backwards-compatibility, mp4

How can i play video in iphone 3G version(MP4 formate)....my coding support only 4g version.

Comment: what is the resolution of your movie file? What format? give some more information, or show your related code

Comment: it is came from web services also mp4 formate i can use MPmovie player

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/message/278621#278621

Answer (score 0):

H264 baseline profile encoding.